# What does "Tops" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"At the time, Deane had four small manufacturers that could make 100 satchels each per week. **Tops**."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/13/this-mom-built-a-65-million-business-the-cambridge-satchel-company.html

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? [tops](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tops): " Slang - adverb - at most - *it'll take us a year, tops*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

> tops

means the *upper limit* or *maximum* amount.